# MySQL query using CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`categories` => `Category_ID`, `Title`, `Description`, `Default_Points`, `Groups`

`transactions` => `Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`

Teachers award points, choosing a category (like "Positive Attitude & Behaviour") and a reason (like "Excellent work today") which puts an entry into the `transactions` table.

A typical `categories` row may be:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`Category_ID`, `Title`, `Description`, `Default_Points`, `Groups`) VALUES
(17, 'Olympic Values', 'Please clearly state the correct Olympic Value that''s being used currently in the REASON box.', 5, '');
```

A typical `transactions` row may be:

```
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`) VALUES
(50, '2011-09-07', 35023, 90236, 5, 17, 'Excellent work during PE');
```

What I'd like to try and do using MySQL is produce a list of total points (i.e. `SUM(transactions.Points)` for EACH category, with a few sample `Reasons` too.

I'd imagine this will have to use a CONCAT?

I need:

- `SUM(transactions.Points)` per category
- `categories.title`
- 5 unique `transactions.reason` per category

This might look like...

```
Points      Title                   Sample
14252       Olympic Values          Excellent work in PE!|Great display of friendship|Well done!
15532       Outstanding Effort      Amazing work!|Worked so hard|Great piece!
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `GROUP_CONCAT` you want.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(t.Points), 
    c.title, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(transactions.reasons SEPERATOR '|'), '|', 5)
FROM transactions t JOIN categories c ON (t.Category_ID=c.Category_ID)
GROUP BY c.Category_ID
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisPatrick. This works nicely apart from the fact that the reasons being returned aren't unique. Generally when the transactions are entered into the database, it'll be in batches of 30 (class size) and as such the first 5 transactions will often be with the same "Reason". Is there anything you can add to make the reasons unique?

Comment: Ahh, got it! Will post it as an answer but give you the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ChrisPatrick 's answer, this is the code I used:

```
SELECT
 SUM(t.Points) AS Total_Points, 
    c.Title, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.reason SEPARATOR '|'), '|', 5) AS Sample_Reasons
FROM
 transactions t JOIN categories c ON (t.Category_ID=c.Category_ID)
GROUP BY c.Category_ID
ORDER BY c.Title ASC
```